# How to add rows dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Does anyone know how to make the button Add Rows work? I want to make if I click that button then rows can be added and the number increased automatically. I've tried, but it doesn't work. Please help. Thank you.

```js
function addRow() {
  var x = document.getElementById('Table');
  var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = x.rows.length;
  new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp1.id += len;
  inp1.value = '';
  var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp2.id += len;
  inp2.value = '';
  x.appendChild(new_row);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" />
  <table id="Table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
      <th>ACTION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where's the input within the rows?

Comment: Please also re-format your question properly and add the code here instead of images

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this to achieve the results:

```js
function addRow() {
    var x = document.getElementById('Table');
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('Table tr').length;
    var new_row = '<tr><th>'+rows+'</th><th> </th><th> </th></tr>';
    x.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',new_row);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()"/>
    <table id="Table" border = "1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <th> </th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```